# Ajax/php getting newest data notification

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, polling

I'm having a little trouble fetching the newest bit of data. All I'm wanting is to find if there is any new data in the database and print the number of records back into my page. I have the ajax working and it has the last notification_id that it sends over to the php. I just need to get the php to select any new data, send it back and print it out.

I haven't yet tried polling, but will look into it when I have this working and understand it a bit better.

```
<?  $call="SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status=1 ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            while($notification_id=mysqli_fetch_array($chant))
            {
                ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){


  var notification_id="<?php echo $notification_id['notification_id'] ;?>"

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(data){
$(".mess"+notification_id).prepend("<span class'mess' id='mes'>"+response['notification_id']+"</span>");

}
});
},20000);

</script>
<? }?>
```

echo '';

PHP viewajax.php - changed it to JSON - but getting {"notification_id":null} in the response

```
   <?php
session_start();
 include"database.php";

if(isset($_GET['notification_id']))
{
$id=$_GET['notification_id'];
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$json = array();
$com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select notification_id from notifications where notification_id>'$id' AND notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status=1");

$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
$json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];
mysqli_free_result($com);


echo json_encode($json);
 }?>
```

Comment: Try to echo the `$json` variable without `json_encode` to check if `notification_id` returns any id or still null. Sometimes `<?php` works but `<?` doesn't

Comment: I get Array in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want new data, why don't you just do `notification_id > '$id'` instead of `notification_id='$id'`?

I assume `notification_id` is an integer index column and `$id` is the last id front-end received.

Comment: Ok tried that, ive changed the php code to JSON_ENCODE, with a response of {"notification_id":null} coming back in firebug

Comment: This means you either get an empty result set or there is a problem with your query. Can you add `echo mysqli_error($mysqli);` after query and `var_dump($resultArr);` after mysqli_fetch_array? Also make sure there is a notification_id bigger than the one you send request.

Comment: Added both and got 

NULL
Array amd yes, there is a bigger value each time it searches.

Comment: Ok i'm getting somewhere now got the following

`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "3299"
  ["notification_id"]=>
  string(4) "3299"
}
{"notification_id":"3299"}`

I just need to edit the php to print out the number of new rows and send it back as a response to print in the front end and then into the allocated div.

Comment: Ok I've fixed it. A little debugging and help has helped me figure it out. Thanks so much guys!